# Culture is not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate version.

I've got this error and I don't know how to solve it.

Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
en-UK is an invalid culture identifier.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException:
>   Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name en-UK is an invalid
>   culture identifier.

please help me

Comment: [CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
en-UK is an invalid culture identifier.]
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride) +202
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name) +6
   ASP.global_asax.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Marcus Evans Documents\MarcusEvans.CMS\CMS.WebUI\Global.asax:142
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

Comment: I have master page in my application, I initialed culture in Application_BeginRequest. am i in right way?

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: You really need to provide more information and context describing on how you got to the error when expecting answers from the community.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should try `en-GB` for English (United Kingdom)

[List of Cultures](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/)

Comment: Thanks Venson, let me try.

Comment: I really appreciate you Venson.

Answer (score 42):

Go to Debug -> Options -> Debugging and tick "Enable Just My Code"

Comment: +1 I'm surprised this was downvoted without comment. It solved this problem for me.

Comment: Agreed.  This suggestion fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks!! You save my life tonight.

Comment: This only hides the error, what actaully is the problem?

Comment: This is more ignoring the problem than solving it. If you need to debug into .net framework code for some reason (Unity...), you'll have to reactivate the setting and this exception will keep nagging you. It would be better to actually understand the root cause and solve the issue.

Comment: Upgrading from Visual Studio 2017 15.4 and 15.5 somehow turned off "Just My Code' - this solved it for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case with IIS Express, it was caused by its inability to write to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files` as IIS Express runs by a current user. So I've added permission to write to it for the current user to solve the error.