# Application gets crashed when system culture is changed giving CultureNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, culture

I have a Winforms application which has a WPF textbox and a Winforms textbox. I have installed a Bhutan locale (Dzongkha), its keyboard and fonts. When the application is running and I change the system culture from [en-US] to [dz-BT](Dzongkha- Bhutan), the moment I try to type something in WPF textbox, application gets crashed, giving a Culture not supported error.
I have tried creating custom culture, but that didn't work for me either.
I am clueless as to how to go about this problem. Any help would be really appreciated.

**Screenshots of the error that occurred** :
[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly said the culture dz-BT is custom and your shot on creating a custom culture did not work. However, you can run a check if the custom culture you created did it get registered properly?

> Referring to the question - [Culture is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425291/culture-is-not-supported)

Try listing all the registered cultures in the system to see if dz-BT is listed or not. You can refer the code here to do this - http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/

If the output list does not have dz-BT then your registration did not go well. You could then inspect the registration of your custom culture little closely. You can get guided by the documentation here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms172469(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I have the custom culture in the list. I registered it when I created it. Its entry is also present in Registry.