# System.ArgumentException: 'The required ID recognition function could not be found. Parameter name: culture '

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, cultureinfo, system.speech.recognition

I get that expection and cannot figure how to solve it.

I've tried changing culture to fi-FI, en-EN, en-GB, en-US it always gives that expection.

I also tried [Culture is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425291/culture-is-not-supported/18951340) solution and `Go to Debug -> Options -> Debugging and tick "Enable Just My Code"` this.

.NET Framework 4.7.2
Visual studio 2019
Reference System.Speech

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace SpeechRecognition3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create an in-process speech recognizer for the en-US locale.  
            using (SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer =
              new SpeechRecognitionEngine(
                new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fi-FI")))
            {

                // Create and load a dictation grammar.  
                recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());

                // Configure input to the speech recognizer.  
                recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

                // Modify the initial silence time-out value.  
                recognizer.InitialSilenceTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

                // Start synchronous speech recognition.  
                RecognitionResult result = recognizer.Recognize();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Recognized text = {0}", result.Text);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No recognition result available.");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the documentation for it
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netcore-3.1

"The format for the culture name based on RFC 4646 is languagecode2>-country/regioncode2, where languagecode2 is the two-letter language code and country/regioncode2 is the two-letter subculture code. "

Comment: umm, i didnt quite understand what should i do now. isnt fi-FI or en-US in right form?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue neither fi-Fi or en-US would work. If someone is still having this problem the following might help.

**The fix was to install [English (US) language package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-a-language-for-windows-ccd853d3-9ecd-7da7-9ef0-72b4a055410a) to windows as a "primary language"** since the local language version of Windows does not include it automatically.

After installing the package `System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")` worked.

*Unfortunately this might also mean that your local language is not a supported natively.*